# Reduce golf cart voltage from 48V to 36V

Tags: voltage

I've got a 48V golf cart. I had a light kit installed. The kit is a 48V kit instead of 12V so there is no voltage reducer. I want to add indicator lights on the dash to let me know when the blinker or flashers are on. I can find 36V indicator lights but not 48V. What can I use to bring the voltage down to 36V for each indicator? The current draw for each light is 6.6mA.

Comment: In theory for some possibilities a suitable resistor might work.  But there's so much practically critical contextual detail missing from your question that's rather dubious if it can be addressed here as an engineering manner, rather than being a product usage question.  What is the actual *nature* of the indicators?   Are they incandescent, or assemblies already consisting of an LED and something like a resistor?

Comment: How many lights? Burning off a 12V difference at 6.6mA as heat is not too bad and you could just use a linear regulator (or resistor if the light doesn't have variable characteristics). But the more lights you have the worse the heat problem gets.